# Bottom Sheet Dialog for RecyclerView Item Click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

In my `recyclerview` there are some items which user can add as favorite.
When user click `+` icon for that item, i will open `Bottom Sheet Dialog` with 2 buttons. `Yes` or `No`. Once I hit yes, favorite will be saved.

I generally do this for normal clicks, but how can I implement this to RecyclerView Adapter for any click?

**Adapter Class**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String urlExtension = "http://192.168.1.110/myapp/public/images";
    Glide.with(context).load(urlExtension+itemList.get(position).getList_image()).into(holder.imageView_list_city);
    holder.textView_list_city_name.setText(itemList.get(position).getList_name());
    holder.textView_list_city_desc.setText(itemList.get(position).getList_description());

    holder.layout_item_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    holder.layout_item_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

**Bottom Sheet Class**

```
public class BottomSheetList extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_add, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need position on after click.

Set OnClickListener in ViewHolder and use `getAdapterPosition()` to get position on clicked item, then call to shoe bottom sheet view

```
 static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Button btnAdd;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


    Holder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        });
    }

    void setItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Interface

```
interface OnItemClickListener {

void onItemClick(int position);
```

}

Set listener

```
holder.setItemClickListener(this);

 @Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    View modelBottomSheet = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(modelBottomSheet);
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try